# php file is not working as src in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I made a dynamic php file to show different text using java script. People uses this to show texts in their website.

They use this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://alquranbd.com/source/q1.php"></script>
```

And the http://alquranbd.com/source/q1.php this file generates a code like this:

```
document.write("এরাই পরকালের বিনিময়ে পার্থিব জীবন ক্রয় করেছে। অতএব এদের শাস্তি লঘু হবে না এবং এরা সাহায্যও পাবে না। (Al-Baqarah-86)");
```

When people using this php file as src in their website this is not showing text. But it was showing text a few weeks ago. Why this is not working now?

Comment: who told you to do like this ? what's the logic behind this ? why not using js scripts to handle this ?

Comment: Because I simply cannot generate a dynamic content to get data from a mysql database using .js file

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: there is a several approaches to do this instead of setting your source like this;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this before any output (at the start of the file)

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: This code is still not working. I have fixed the question please check it

Comment: your url still respons with the header: text/html, so you did not succesfully implement my solution yet.

Comment: Where should I add header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8'); this? Inside the php file?